# /etc/fstab contents seem to be wrong but they aren't

Tags: debian, mount, boot, fstab

I manually created the partitions, copied a rootfs inside an appropriate one, `chroot`ed into the rootfs, installed a kernel and Grub, just like I did million times before. I exactly use the same disk layout and boot process (without creating the rootfs from "scratch") as my current host.

Current problem is that the boot process hangs with

```
A start job is running for ...some-UUID-beginning...73
A start job is running for ...some-UUID-beginning...67
```

message, then boot fails and a rescue shell is present. System is Debian Buster, initially created with:

```
sudo lxc-create -n erik3 -t debian -- -r buster
```

Disk layout is:

```
NAME                FSTYPE      FSVER    LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sdc                                                                                                  
├─sdc1              ext2        1.0            fe2cfe8c-28d3-455c-961e-b586cf763367    224.8M    17% /mnt/zencefil-root-rootfs/boot
└─sdc2              crypto_LUKS 2              32d6e3b6-1e75-4d40-86c2-5a8853996e73                  
  └─zencefil_crypt  LVM2_member LVM2 001       ttASfx-WjIt-tuhW-AjRN-6tiJ-dnuI-AU8GgN                
    ├─zencefil-swap swap        1              286b4d65-5ca6-4453-b904-6d56749fed0f                  
    └─zencefil-root btrfs                      655c3de0-2963-46d1-bc0f-a6a8690632ad    896.1G     3% /mnt/zencefil-root
```

When I enter my root password to examine the situation, I noticed that commenting out some necessary lines in `/etc/fstab` (and rebooting) still doesn't prevent boot from hanging for 1m30s but lets the system boot up correctly.

I double checked the contents of `/etc/fstab` file and it has to be correct:

```
/dev/mapper/zencefil-root /               btrfs        subvol=rootfs,rw,noatime       0       1
##UUID=fe2cfe8c-28d3-455c-961e-b586cf763367     /boot   ext2    defaults,noatime        0       2
###/dev/mapper/zencefil-root /mnt/zencefil-root       btrfs        subvolid=5,rw,noatime       0       1
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,mode=1777,size=512M 0 0
```

(the `##...` and `###...` lines are necessary but commenting them out lets the system display the login screen after 1m30s)

There is even no typo in `fstab`. Here is the proof:

```
grep "^##\w" /etc/fstab | sed -e 's/^##//' \
        | awk '{print "mount " $1 " " $2 " -t " $3 " -o " $4}' \
        | xargs -L 1 -I {} sh -c "echo {}; {}"
```

Above script parses the `fstab` file for the line `##...`, constructs a `mount ...` command and executes it, which in turn succeeds:

```
mount UUID=fe2cfe8c-28d3-455c-961e-b586cf763367 /boot -t ext2 -o defaults,noatime
root@erik3:~# mount | grep boot
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,noatime)
```

However, leaving the same line uncommented out in `/etc/fstab` doesn't mount the `/boot`. Why?

The `... / ...` line in `/etc/fstab` makes `/` partition mounted in `rw`. Commenting out that line causes `/` partition mounted in `ro` (which is initially performed by initrd), as expected. So `/etc/fstab` file is absolutely regarded.

What is the subsystem that displays the "A start job is running..." messages?

Comment: You might want to check the answers here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/711016/slow-boot-a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-disk-by

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Accepted answer and many others require to remove non-present devices, which is not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that using the rootfs that is created with LXC is inappropriate for creating real installations. We should use `multistrap` instead.

The steps to fully produce above problem is available at [multistrap-helpers@2ada86fd](https://github.com/ceremcem/multistrap-helpers/tree/2ada86fd38e0cec786d8f0302f4d4da66e94d8d6). If you create the rootfs with multistrap, then `install-to-disk` instructions works perfectly. If you create the rootfs with `lxc-create`, that problem happens.